# git pull gives failed access timed out

Tags: git, github

I have a problem with git pull (and I am rather new to git)
So I know there have been changes to te origin/master branch on github (git bash also told me so) So I want to do an update using:

```
git pull
```

However this gives me an error:

```
fatal: unable to access '(adres)': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
```

While searching I found solutions involving proxysettings and problems on githubs side. As far as I could tell from the page, github is not having any issues at the moment.

The proxyI do not fully understand. I have been able before to clone and push to this repository so I do not fully understand why pull all of a sudden would require proxy settings.

I am using git bash on a windows 10 computer. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you did not need a proxy before, you should need one now.

But the first test is to check if you can access https://github.com at all (on your browser), meaning to check if there is no network issue (firewall?) between your computer and GitHub.

You can also check if an SSH access would work (provided you have [a default public rsa key registered to GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh))

```
git ls-remote git@github:me/myrepo
```

Answer (score 0):

**Adding a new ssh key solved the problem for me**

Step 1 : https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Step 2 : https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account